# Building DimDate in SSAS 2012 for Persian calendar (Shamsi or Jalali dates)

Tags: t-sql, date, ssis, dimensions, persian

Does anybody have a script for building DimDate in SSAS 2012 for Persian calendar (Shamsi or Jalali dates)?

I found scripts for building the structure here:
http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MikeDavis/ssis/1400/script-to-load-dim-date-and-dim-time

I want to know what you use to convert dates to Shamsi dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get date conversion script from below resources.

- [T-SQL Gregorian To Persian Converter](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/50-T-SQL-Gregorian-To-Persian-Converter.html)

  Main function is the

> [dbo].[GregorianToPersian]

which you can use it in this syntax:

> ```
> select [dbo].[GregorianToPersian] ('2011-08-25)
>
> result: 1390-06-03
> ```

- [Getting Shamsi Date From Gregorian Date](http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/getting-shamsi-date-from-gregorian-date/)

> SELECT dbo.getShamsiDate('20130430')

And the result is:

```
1392/02/10
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created an sql-server script and a csv file alongside it
you can get it on github
[date dimension table for Uk, US, and persians](https://github.com/afshinamiree/dim_date_persian)