# How to convert a date to char(8) in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a date value like:

```
declare @d date = getDate();
```

Its result is '2023/11/05'

I want to convert it to '20231105' and save it into column of datatype char(8)

Comment: Storing data using the wrong data types is almost always a bad idea. If you're storing dates, store them in a date column. Leave *formatting* concerns to your presentation or reporting tools. In the alternative, try writing a `CHECK` constraint for that `char(8)` column that ensures e.g. that `20240229` is valid but neither `20240230` nor `20230229` is. If you keep `date`, you don't have to write such validation, it's literally impossible to store invalid values.

Comment: It's possible if your calendar is Miladi,
but in other calendars, it's difficult to store date into a date field.
I check and validate the date in my c# app.

Comment: What type of calendar are you using that won't let you store a date? You are likely confusing the format with the physical storage (which is completely seperate and not dependant on format)

Comment: When you check and validate the date in your app, are you using a C# date data type? Because app developers will give you exactly the same advice: don't store dates in string data types, store them in date data types. I am intrigued as to what use case stops you doing this? Can you give an example date that you think can't be stored correctly? February 30th?

Comment: It's impossible in shamsi calendar to save exactly in database
I inserted '1402/12/25' in Date field, but in SSMS it show it '2024-03-15'
And I cant run query like "select * from Table where sendDate between 1400 and 1402" but it's easy in char or int fields , and so on

Comment: You might find these SO post useful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/6706692/3094533
https://stackoverflow.com/q/43180173/3094533
https://stackoverflow.com/q/24586686/3094533

Comment: As SQL Server only supports the Gregorian calendar have you considered just storing dates in that calendar and converting to and from shamsi calendar as needed?

Comment: This is an interesting challenge. Do you ever need to do date arithmetic (add or subtract days, add or subtract months) if not, then yes it probably makes sense to store as an int. But back to your original question, `getdate()` won't return current date in shamsi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the format, but my recommend is to use the DimDate(Table Date) and where clause with date and use dateint in select

```
Select format(cast(GETDATE() as date),'yyyyMMdd') --20230626

Select format(cast('2023/11/05' as date),'yyyyMMdd') --20231105
```

Comment: Be careful here. That date literal can cause issues depending on the language settings. The only 100% safe date string format is YYYYMMDD with no dashes or slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `FORMAT` it's slow, and should only be used if you have no choice.

**Just use `CONVERT` with [style 112](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).**

```sql
select convert(char(8), @d, 112);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZQEUeOyf)

Having said that, I'd advise you not to save that into a column. Dates should be kept in date formats, not `varchar`, until you actually need to query it.

At the most, you could use a computed column

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD FormattedDate AS ( CONVERT(char(8), YourDateColumn, 112) )
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this code:

```
select    FORMAT( getdate()  ,'yyyyMMdd')
```